# Calculate paid to date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access table with weekly charges and a table with payments towards those charges.  Now I need to determine the date until which the payments have covered.

as an example vendor1 is charging $500 per week with first invoice being 1/1/19, his payments totals $1000, I want to show that he's paid up to 1/15/19

My database is brand new so I'm free to alter the structure as needed...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can't think of any way to get this done. Besides manually applying payments to charges. Which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Probably require custom function. Question is too broad for SO. It's simple to calculate a balance due but to determine if particular invoices are partially or fully not paid, gets complicated. Especially when payment amounts are not exactly same as invoice amounts.

Comment: I'm not looking to get the whether a particular invoice has been paid or not. I try to get a date up to which this payments covers. this is not related to programing. it must be doable with a sql query

Comment: a SQL question without any DDL, Data and SQL statement, is NOT a good SQL question.

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

```
PaidUntil = DateDiff("ww", Int(TotalPaid / WeeklyPayment), FirstInvoiceDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Access provides functions for working with dates:  Because you want to display the data you will want a report like:
[image]

here is a table structure and a query to serve as the data source for the report:
[image]

Account Balance: Sum([Payments]![PaymentAmount])-Sum([Charges].[Chargeamount])

Months Ahead: -Int(-([Account Balance]/Max([Subscriptions]![SubscriptionAmount])))

Next Payment Date: DateAdd("m",[Months Ahead],[LastPaymentDate])

the query gives the following results with the mock data I used:

[image]

Months ahead uses two work arounds: max is used to make subscription amount a group level variable.  -int is a way to make access round up:

[Q: How to ROUNDUP a number in Access 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980106/q-how-to-roundup-a-number-in-access-2013)